# Windows 2008. cannot connect via RDP anymore after changes to Firewall port settings

Tags: windows, windows-server-2008, authentication, rdp

After successfully changing default RDP port on remote Windows 2008 R2, I configured that inbound rule to apply only to authenticated connections (because i needed to assign ONLY specific users to be able to remotely connect).

Once I selected the option (something like that) "allow this rule only to authenticated connections".. the remote server disconnected me and I can no longer reach server via RDP.

How can I access again? Any advice for me please?

Comment: You will have to psychically be there and make the changes unless you have some sort of IP based KVM to connect with?

Comment: Did you do this due to the recent security vulnrability in rdp, if so this won't mitigate a thing.

Comment: @colt T: this means that i have to request a KVM from my provider.. thank you.

Comment: @tonyroth: no, i did it in order to allow only specific users to log in via RDP

Comment: What are my options to secure server to allow rdp only from specific users without messing up again.. any recommendations for me?

Comment: I'd setup direct access for one, the following docs should help. http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd758757(v=WS.10).aspx

Comment: KVM from hosting provider solved my issue, i can log in again. Thank you!. Thanks Tony, looks very interesting.. i will give it a try :-) have a nice day!

Comment: ah yes kvm is your friend in this case!

Answer (score 0):

If you can't use Remote Registry to change the settings by hand, you'll need direct console access to log in. An IP KVM, or LOM console would do the trick.

Answer (score 0):

> What are my options to secure server to allow rdp only from specific users without messing up again.

I don't know about the firewall part, but you can you just exclude certain users from membership in the "Remote Desktop Users" group, or similar group with the remote desktop rights denied.  The users will presumably still connect to the server, but will get a message about how they are not allowed to log in.